# At what point the process of breaking a magnet stop?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If I break a magnet, I get two magnets.
Now I could repeat this with one the two halves.
If I keep going, eventually the magnet will be smaller than the size of an atom, so, one of two things should happen before reaching that point:

1. I separate the two poles
2. I cannot break the magnet anymore

I know 1. is impossible, since we cannot separate the two poles, so I am guessing the process need to stop at some point. At what point will I be unable to break my magnet, and why?

Comment: You may find this article interesting and relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for a "classic" magnet consisting of iron, the process stops when you get down to a single atom. If you split that into a pair of smaller atoms, neither is going to be a magnet anymore.

Comment: what do you mean by "smaller" atoms?

Comment: I mean taking the iron atom and pulling its nucleus apart to make two separate, smaller nuclei- for example, 2 aluminum nuclei- and dressing them with the correct number of electrons. Those aluminum atoms cannot be magnetized and will not be attracted to a magnet.